# How server intensive is AppendToLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, iis-7

We are using C# to append to our logs using the following:

HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendToLog("Custom Text Here");

We want to have this line run on every page request for every customer by putting this in our master pages. For 30k+ customers daily on every request just yells suicide. We already have problems keeping our servers up and running. So my question, how much of a hit would this be on our servers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you tell us... I suggest you farm your server and enable it on one server. The major source of contention would be synchronization of log access. No idea how IIS internally handles/queues that (I hope it does so in async mode)

Comment: Why not just load test it and see?  Likely it isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have already ran into this problem and have the answer. I will be doing load testing regardless but the stack overflow world always has helpful information.